# phpexcel Fatel Error when opening file

Tags: phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am trying to open an excel file on my hard drive and getting.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1032 
bytes) in C:\WEB\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 1228
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP allows 128 MB memory to use.

try this

```
<?php ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); ?>
```

Comment: time depends on the file size ;)

Comment: 2.97 MB two sheets that's all. and on my hard drive? WOW

Comment: @jimneely Decompressed data will always require more memory than compressed data